# Associating two models in different ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models. `user` & `rule`
and two different cases

- `user` can create a `rule`
- `user` can assign a rule to another `user`

For first case I'm doing:

```
class User
  has_many :rules #owner or the rule
end

class Rule
  belongs_to :user
end
```

For second case: (`rule` can also be applied to other models, so I've made it polymorphic)

```
class User
  has_many :rules, as: :rulable #rules applied to the user
end

class Rule
  belongs_to :rulable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now if I want to get rules created by a user, and rules applied to a user separately, how would I go about it.

Comment: Do it like this: `has_many :rules_applied, as: :rulable, class_name: 'Rule'` So `user.rules`will return created rules and `user.rules_applied` will return applied rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never necessary to have the association name same as model name you can define it something else and mention the class name. So in your case you can do like this:

```
class User
  has_many :rules #owner or the rule
  has_many :rules_applied, as: :rulable, class_name: 'Rule' #rules applied to the user
end

class Rule
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rulable, polymorphic: true
end
```

So `user.rules` will return created rules and `user.rules_applied` will return applied rules.

And `rule.user` will return the owner and `rule.rulable` will return the user on which rule is applied.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Instead of changing applied rules to `rules_applied`, can I change the name of owned rules to something else? Since its a polymorphic association, now I have to change in all the other models.

Comment: Yes you can the same way by giving `class_name`

Comment: Thanks. That did it.